# "Flattening" complex sequences of related rows in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with events describing user navigation through flows, with this general shape (disregard the timestamps, I smashed some keys):

```
user timestamp event_name event_choice
1    12345678  start
1    45678912  choose     option_a
1    45678912  end
```

After the `option_a` event, users can go back and choose another option:

```
2    83475656  start
2    45678912  choose     option_a
2    93847398  back
2    45678912  choose     option_b
2    23487383  end
```

Users can also go through a flow multiple times:

```
3    83475656  start
3    45678912  choose     option_a
3    93847398  end
3    93847398  start
3    45678912  choose     option_b
3    23487383  end
```

I want to produce a table where each row represents a flow, from `start` to `end`, including the selected option along the way. For example:

```
user start_at  end_at   choice
1    83475656  23487383 option_a
2    83475656  23487383 option_b
3    83475656  23487383 option_a
3    83475656  23487383 option_b
```

I need to avoid:

1. False results from the `back` event changing the option mid-flow.
2. False results from mixing up two different instances of the flow.
3. False results from mixing up two different users.

I have no idea how to approach this. If it's any difference, I'm using BigQuery, which has some differences with standard SQL and may have some specific functions.

Comment: what is expected output for users 2 and 3?

Comment: I edited the question to include all expected results (two for the last user, on for each instance of the flow). Once again, disregard the timestamps haha

Comment: obviously - values you provided for `timestamp` column are very confusing and make not much sense if at all - but hopefully below answer gets it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add up the `starts` to assign a grouping.  Then you want the last option in each group:

```
select user, min(timestamp) as start_at, max(timestamp) as stop_at,
       array_agg( event_choice ignore nulls order by timestamp desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)] as choice
from (select t.*,
             countif(event_name = 'start') over (partition by user order by timestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by user, grp;
```

This makes some assumptions about the data, notably:

- `'start'` and `'stop'` are lined up.
- you want the most recent non-null `option_choice`.

Comment: Worderful! I believe the query should `order by timestamp DESC` in `array_agg`, to leave the latest timestamp in the first ordinal, shouldn't it?